# i686 versus i486 kernel on an Intel Core i3

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, cpu

I had installed Debian 6 Squeeze on my laptop a couple of weeks ago. Coming from Ubuntu, I did this by downloading the hybrid [i386 image](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/release/current-live/i386/iso-hybrid/) and booting it off a USB drive.

Now on GRUB, I'm presented with two kernels—a i486 one and a i686 one. Since the i686 one was at the top and as I didn't know anything about kernel architectures, I didn't care much and have been using it so far.

But in the last few days I've been have nothing but trouble. The system crashes without warning, and sometimes shows a kernel panic.

As a last attempt I tried using the i486 kernel and things have been going smoothly. My laptop's processor is a first generation Intel Core i3. What may have caused the problem? And why didn't I get two different kernels when I used to run Ubuntu?

Comment: As for why this didn't happen with Ubuntu: their big selling point is (or at least has been represented to me as) *not making new users make decisions*. So, only the most compatible kernel will be visible unless you jump through some hoops to change things.

Answer (score 5):

The i686 version is for all current Intel-compatible processor; the i486 version is for special/old hardware that is only compatible to the Intel 80486.

For your Intel Core i3, you can also use the 64-bit version (amd64) or the 32-bit "-bigmem" version, which provide both more security features.

If you have problems with the Squeeze i686 kernel you can try to switch to a newer kernel from [Debian Backports](http://backports-master.debian.org/).

See for example [this FAQ](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAMD64Faq) for more information about the 64-bit version.